# Jade conditional statements rendered as plain text

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am trying to conditionally render some tags in my  `<head>`

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html ng-app='nodeApp'>

    <head>
        if (title)
            <title>#{title}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name='author' content='#{author}'>
        <meta name='og:title' content='#{title}'>
        <meta name='description' content='#{description}'>
        <meta name='og:description' content='#{description}'>
        <meta name='og:image' content='#{image}'>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#3F51B5">
        <!-- CSS files are inserted here -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/client.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
```

When I go to my page the text "if (title)" is rendered in plain text at the top of the page. This happens to ALL conditionals.. however, the title tag is rendered with the correct text.

I have also tried

```
if title
            <title>#{title}</title>
```

and

```
if (title) {
            <title>#{title}</title>
}
```

in my backend I have (throughout the class)..

```
const jade = require('jade');
this.locals = {
                title: process.env.sitename
            };
this.header = jade.render(this.header, this.locals);
```

So sitename is returned correctly because the title gets populated, but the if statements don't do anything and just get rendered as plain text. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Verified generically: `require('jade').render('if title\n  <title>#{title}</title>', { title: 'test' })`, which returns the expected string: `'<title>test</title>'`

Comment: @Ixe I added a bit more context to see if that helps

Comment: with the addition of the template, I get the following error: 

`
Error: ./file.template:2
    1| <!doctype html>
  > 2|     <html ng-app='nodeApp'>
    3|
    4|     <head>
    5|         if (title)

unexpected token "indent"
`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you are mixing writing regular html with jade. 
Since you are writing with regular html-tags the if-statement is already a child to head. But then you use indentation as well and it becomes sort of a double indentation and Jade gets confused.
Try this without indentation before the if-statement:

```
<head>
if (title)
  <title>#{title}</title>
```

Or better yet. Use Jade consistently.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try this out. I was hoping to only use jade for the variables, since I don't like the syntax and my website is already written in normal HTML. I'm currently looking for other options that may work better for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepend a hyphen for the javascript statements like [here](http://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/03e3ed03e1d9c6562b60c34c48164a41?editors=1000).

```
- var title = true;

- if (title) {
    h1(title='#{title}') My Title
- }
```

Comment: Not according to their docs? "Jade's first-class conditional syntax allows for optional parenthesis, and you may now omit the leading - otherwise it's identical, still just regular javascript:"

Comment: I tried this to be sure and it did not solve the issue.